# How to split an object in a video

Tags: premiere

I trying to find a way to do the animation of separating different components of a computer window as it is done in the following video using adobe premiere pro.
Could somebody help me to put some light on how to achieve this in premiere pro

the time of the animation starts at 3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd typically tackle something like this in After Effects, but since Premiere Pro is the restriction here, lets give it a go;

1. Screenshot/Screen Record the application you wish to deconstruct.
2. Import the footage into Premiere.
3. Count how many components you'll be splitting the footage into and duplicate the footage that number of times.
4. On each duplication, use [the rectangular mask in premiere](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=premiere%20pro%20masking) to isolate the different components of the application.
5. You now have control over the position of each components you isolated. Use positional keyframes to animate as you wish.